# use buttons to define a value to a string

Tags: android, xml, button

I'm new to android programming and i would like to know if there's any way to use a button in the main.xml file or if i should just go ahead and make my screen with a custom ui from scratch in my main panel.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can, and find your button by:

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can get a reference to the button object that the button in your layout xml represents. You can do whatever you want to it, including set listeners that will do things when it gets clicked.